# Plotting dates with plot_date

Tags: python, date, datetime, matplotlib

I have a bunch of dates in the form `MM / DD / YYYY`.  I use a parser to get them into something that looks like `datetime.datetime(YYYY, MM, DD, 0, 0)`
.

I have data corresponding to each date in an array `y` and would like to plot the two arrays against one another.  Using `matplotlib.dates.date2num` I plot them as

```
x= matplotlib.dates.date2num(dates)

plot_date(dates,y)
```

When I do this, I get the following plot

[image]

Where as I would prefer something that looks like a time series.

How can I fix this

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the dates and data that you're reading in are not in time order, in which case you'll need to sort them both before they're passed to `plot_date()`:

```
s = np.argsort(dates)
plot_date(dates[s],y[s])
```

This should work whether you sort on the list/array of `datetime` instances (your `dates`) or their numerical equivalents (your `x`).